# Uploading purchased (edited) music to YouTube

Tags: copyright, internet, music

Say that a hobbyist DJ purchases CDs, digital tracks and what are known as mixtapes (free music) and slows them down or things like that.  If that DJ wants to share the result of this, is it legal to upload and try to monetize it?

Let's say that the DJ also places small sample noises to signify that it’s their work.

Answer (score 2):

### No

These are derivative works and making them is copyright breach.

Doing this as a hobby or even for the entertainment of friends in private is likely fair use. Distribution or performance in public (monitored or not) is likely not fair use and you would need a licence.

[Here](http://www.musicrights.com.au/fact-sheets/making-adaptions/) is a summary of the relevant law in [australia](/questions/tagged/australia).

Comment: Okay then a license it is, is this a state license? Would I be able to produce and distribute anything I wanted?

Comment: @JohnnyT it’s a licence issued by each individual copyright holder. In some countries, there is a body authorised by law to collect statutory royalties on music performance but for re-recording, for most you need to find and get permission from the copyright holder and pay them the royalties you agree with them.

Comment: As man that sounds like a headache, and a waiting process.

Comment: @JohnnyT man if someone was monetizing _your_ work (with additional production of their own) would you have no objections? Would you not hold them liable for not trying to make a deal with you?

Comment: There’s about 5-10 major music labels I’d have to write in and persuade to allow me to reproduce purchased content.

Comment: @JohnnyT yes. That’s called “doing business”.

Comment: Right lol maybe I should reach out to them.. thank your for the info I’m sure they have a service section for this.